# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' after computer shut down and pip install

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, modulenotfounderror

I am using Mac and python 3.9. I shut down my computer and when I turned it back on I got ModuleNotFoundErrors for packages I was using previously including Jupyter and Pandas. Both show up when I try
`pip list`

I tried using pip install pandas and it says

```
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in ./miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (1.5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.1 in ./miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in ./miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pandas) (2022.4)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.20.3 in ./miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pandas) (1.23.5)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in ./miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.1->pandas) (1.16.0)
```

I am noticing errors for other packages too that were previously working fine.

Comment: _shut down my computer and when I turned it back on_ Did you have a virtual environment, that you forgot to reactivate after the reboot?

Comment: @JohnGordon I was using the packages outside of a virtual environment before I shut down, and tried running the same script after.

Comment: @Wayne But the jupyter notebook isnt running inside of a virtual environment so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error if the package is installed on my machine (where the notebook is also running)

Comment: It is installed to where your `pip list` is running; however, that doesn't seem to be what Jupyter is using as it's environment to run the kernel. Oh wait, miniforge is conda based so you should use `%conda install -c conda-forge pandas` and not pip to be installing things anyway. Ancaonda/conda is your primary package manager if it is involved. Only use pip when you have to in that case, for any an all packages. 'Environments' is a concept you'll want to start learning about. Just because something is installed on your computer somewhere doesn't mean it's used everywhere. Plus, ...

Comment: <continued> environments allow you to isolate your projects and have say one versions of Pandas for an old project and a new version for a new project. Or even more typically, built around old vs new versions of Python. That way you don't break your old projects when you start a new project with the newest version(s) involved. Oversimplification but that is a bit of the basis for project management using environments. Note the mention of 'environment'  quite a few times on the page https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge .

Comment: See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) about the modern magic install commands that you can run inside notebooks so the installs occur in the environments where the kernel is running that is underlying the active notebook. You can specify versions in the variations of those commands, too,

Comment: @Wayne Yeah I think I am just going to put this all in environment so I dont have to worry about this next time. Thanks!